# Google Apps Add editors folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a list of email user in `Listvalideur[]`. I have created a folder.

1. How can I add editor right to the new folder with this `Listvalideur`? These few lines don't work:

   ```
   var folder = optFolder.createFolder(folderName); 
   for (var i=0; i<Listvalideur.length; i++) {
       folder.addEditor(Listvalideur[i][0]);
   }
   ```
2. Can you also give me the syntax for `folder.addeditors` methods? These 2 syntaxs don't work:

   ```
   folder.addEditors('xxx1.yyy1@vvv.com','xxx2.yyyy2@vvv.com');
   folder.addEditors('xxx1.yyy1@vvv.com,xxx2.yyyy2@vvv.com');
   ```

Thanks a lot

Thks for your answer.
In fact my array is only one dimension Listvalideur[i]. I get this variable from a spreadsheet sheet Call $ListValideur

```
   |       A 
1  |  email1@etc
2  |  email2@example
```

I use this syntax to read and set a array call listvalideur[]

```
var Listvalideur = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sskeyTable)
     .getSheetByName('$ListValideur')
     .getDataRange‌​()
     .getValues();
```

Now I want to Add all email user from my array listvalideur[] to acces to a folder.

I try this syntax without manage :

```
var folder = optFolder.createFolder(folderName); 
folder.addEditors(ListValideur[]);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. In your question you say that you have a list of emails in `Listvalideur` variable. Is it really a one dimension array (e.g. a list) or a matrix? Because on your code you write `Listvalideur[i][0]`. Try `Listvalideur[i]` only. Or show us how you get/create this variable. The rest of the code looks fine.
2. You need to pass an array of emails, e.g. *(notice the brackets)*

   ```
   folder.addEditors(['email1@etc', 'email2@example']);
   ```

Comment: Thks for your answer.
In fact my array is only one dimension Listvalideur[i].

I get this variable from a spreadsheet list

var Listvalideur = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sskeyTable).getSheetByName('$ListValideur').getDataRange().getValues();


For example :

Listvalideur[0]='email1@etc';
Listvalideur[1]='email2@*example';

So with your syntax :
folder.addEditors(['email1@etc', 'email2@example']);

how I can use my array to initialise editors :
**folder.addEditors(ListValideur[]);**

Comment: Here in Stackoverflow you can edit your question to add new information or just make it better. Comments are not suitable for a lot of code like this. Anyway, when you do a `getValues()`, you'll always get a 2-dimension array, not matter the range. So your assumption that Listvalideur is one dimension is wrong. Please edit your question so I can answer it properly. By the way, is your data in one column or one row?